# Unable to post data to survey controller in yii

Tags: yii

### index.php

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('items_update', 
"$('#dropit').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '".Yii::app()->createUrl('survey/questions')."',
        data:
            {
                _designation : test,
            },
        type: 'POST',
        success:function()
            { 
                console.log('success');
            },
        error:function()
            { 
                console.log('failure');
            }
        });
    return false;
    });    
");
?>


<div id="surveyupdate">
<?php 
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('dropit', '', 
     array(                                             
  'Reception'=>'Service Reception', 
  'SA'=>'ServiceAdvisor','Billing'=>'Billing Staff',          
  'Parts'=>'Parts Counter','Cashier'=>'Cashier','Cwd'=>'Customer Welfare Desk'),
     array('prompt'=>'- select -'));
?>
</div>

<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'itemView'=>'_view',    
            'id'=>'ajaxListView',
            ));
?>
```

### controller 'survey.php'

```
 public function actionQuestions()
{   
    //debugging purposes
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    exit;
}
```

### To Do's

What I'm trying to do is to update the **CListView** by getting the selected data from **dropdownlist** via **POST** that to be evaluated by the controller, get the data from database and update the **CListview**.

Please help me. I'm just newly learning Yii. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Id for dropdownList, like below

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('dropit', '', 
     array(                                             
  'Reception'=>'Service Reception', 
  'SA'=>'ServiceAdvisor','Billing'=>'Billing Staff',          
  'Parts'=>'Parts 
  Counter','Cashier'=>'Cashier','Cwd'=>'Customer Welfare 
  Desk'),
 array('prompt'=>'- select -', 'id'=>'dropit')); // added I'd here
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. I tried your suggestion by adding ID just like you have mentioned, unfortunately I'm still unable to fire the execution for ajax :(

Comment: Have you register jquery? because ajax code is depends on jquery.

Comment: Based on my sites' page source:

<script type="text/javascript" src="/tcosurvey/assets/e407dad/jquery.js"></script>

Is this how to register jquery: Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?

I already did but no luck

Comment: I see, I haven't tested the console part on inspect element yet.

Console show "success", so the ajax functioned well. Thank you. By the way, how do I get the value of the posted data? I assume I posted something like $_POST['_designation'] = test.

I would like to assign the data to a variable inside surveycontroller